# NTOSKRNL.EXE vs NTKRNLMP.EXE vs NTKRNLPA.EXE vs NTKRPAMP.EXE

Tags: kernel

NTOSKRNL.EXE  vs NTKRNLMP.EXE vs NTKRNLPA.EXE vs NTKRPAMP.EXE

what differ it

i have intel core2 duo processor , my kernel file must be which ?

Answer (score 7):

"NTKRNLMP.EXE vs NTKRNLMP.EXE vs NTKRNLMP.EXE" <-- no difference here. Please consider rewriting your question to include some more detail and try googling the different exe's yourself.

Included is the ["explanation" from wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl)

> Names of kernel
>
> - NTOSKRNL.EXE : 1 CPU
> - NTKRNLMP.EXE : N CPU SMP
> - NTKRNLPA.EXE : 1 CPU, PAE
> - NTKRPAMP.EXE : N CPU SMP, PAE

So basically the NTOSKRNL.EXE is the NT kernel for 1 CPU, NTKRNLPA.EXE is for 1 CPu with physical address extension (PAE) support. NTKRNLMP.EXE is for multiple CPUs, NTKRPAMP.EXE is for multiple CPUs + PAE.

Comment: Note, x64 is always multiprocessor and there is no PAE, so they are called hal.dll and ntoskrnl.exe instead of halmapic.dll and ntkrnlmp.exe